# Typescript how to check if a function is defined (plugin, window.plugin)

Tags: typescript

I'm converting in Typescript an existing js file which makes this check:

```
if (typeof sweetAlert == "function") {               
    swal(title, message, "error");
} else {
    alert(message);
}
```

but i get both `Cannot find name 'sweetAlert'` nor `Cannot find name 'swal'`

How to make a similar check in Typescript, and calling the swal function maybe defined elsewhere?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the compiler know that this `sweetAlert` exists:

```
interface Window {
    sweetAlert: Function;
}

if (typeof sweetAlert == "function") {               
    sweetAlert(title, message, "error");
} else {
    alert(message);
}
```

---

#### Edit

Try using `declare`:

```
declare function sweetAlert(title: string, message: string, type: string);

if (typeof sweetAlert == "function") {               
    sweetAlert(title, message, "error");
} else {
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Are you using both `sweetAlert` and `swal`?

Comment: I've changed the second line to sweetAlert too, but the compiler gives to me the same error.

Comment: Maybe some compiler option in tsconfig, such as noImplicitAny = true, strictNullChecks = true?

Comment: Try my revised answer

Comment: Ok, the code now compiles, but in that way the sweetAlert function would be *always* defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "always defined"?

Comment: I mean, by using `declare function sweetAlert`, then the check `typeof sweetAlert == "function"` will be always true?

Comment: No. That depends on how you use typescript (for example, are you using a module system with import/export?). But generally if you want that in more than one file then you better put it in a `.d.ts` file and then import it or reference to it wherever you need it